# How to capture the integer or point number from string?

Tags: string, design-patterns, lua, match

I have this string

```lua
S = "564186207, 399.4989929 , ABC, degds, 2425, 335.232"
```

and I want to capture the only integer and point number.

Like this:

```
string.gfind(S, ???)
     --> 564186207, 399.4989929, 2425, 335.232
```

I have tried:

```lua
string.gfind(S, "%d+")
string.gfind(S, "%d\*")
string.gfind(S, "^%d")
```

How can I capture the only number from that string?

Comment: `for found in S:gmatch("[%d%.]+") do print(found) end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of Lua have replaced `gfind` with `gmatch`, replace the function in the code to match your version.

Since you want to match both integers and decimals you will need a pattern that includes both. You want to match: a sequence of numbers, possibly followed by a dot and then more numbers.

```
local S = "564186207, 399.4989929 , ABC, degds, 2425, 335.232"
local pattern = "(%d+%.?%d*)" --Any number of digits, followed by an optional 'dot' and then zero or more digits (this could match against "123." but given your example input it hopefully won't be an issue
local matches = string.gmatch(S,pattern)
for found in matches do
    print("Matched:",found)
end
```

Outputs:

```
Matched:    564186207
Matched:    399.4989929
Matched:    2425
Matched:    335.232
```

Comment: This doesn't match negative number (-123.45) but you're example didn't include any. Let me know if that is an issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. you solve all of my problem